# How to transfer tkinter windows but delete respowaning ones (Closed)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a python file that creates a canvas and records variables using IntVar and I want them to be transferred to another file, called Endscreen. But when I run the second file the first file comes up again. I suspect it is to do with "from GAM import hits, hits_on_target, root"

I tried root.destroy(), but it says it has already been destroyed.

```py
#the first python file
hits, hits_on_target = tk.IntVar(root), tk.IntVar(root)
#this is how hits and hits_on_target are recorded
def hitcounter(event):
    hits.set(hits.get() + 1)
    if is_target_hit(event.x, event.y): #for every click on the canvas
        hits_on_target.set(hits_on_target.get() + 1)
...
def endscreens():
    root.destroy()
    import Endscreen
```

```py
#the second python file
import tkinter as tk
from GAM import hits, hits_on_target, root

scorehits, scorehits_on_target = hits.get(), hits_on_target.get()

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

widget = tk.Label(canvas, text=str(scorehits)+ ' ' +str(scorehits_on_target))
widget.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want the program to be able to open the new py file's canvas by itself

If there any problems please feel free to comment, thanks!

Although I have not found the true true problem, I have decided to just run the second file by itself as it runs the first file anyway

Comment: Change `print(hits, hits_on_target)` to `print(hits.get(), hits_on_target.get())`. That said I am not sure we can fix your other errors without a testable example code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Silly me, but how do I stop the previous file from opening again do I root.delete() it and create a new one?

Comment: I feel your ***"#the second python file"*** should be the ***"#the first python file"** becaus there is the line `root = tk.Tk()` which must be called **once** and **first**. Also read about [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules)